# Python : Remove all data in a column of a dataframe and keep the last value in the first row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say that I have a simple Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [12,34,'fsdf',678,'','','dfs','','']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Data'])
print(df1)

   Data
0    12
1    34
2  fsdf
3   678
4
5
6   dfs
7
8
```

I want to delete all the data except the last value found in the column that I want to keep in the first row. It can be an column with thousands of rows. So I would like the result :

```
   Data
0   dfs
1   
2  
3  
4
5
6  
7
8
```

And I have to keep the shape of this dataframe, so not removing rows.

What are the simplest functions to do that efficiently ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get index of last not empty string value and pass to first value of column:

```
s = df1.loc[df1['Data'].iloc[::-1].ne('').idxmax(), 'Data']
print (s)
dfs

df1['Data'] = ''
df1.loc[0, 'Data'] = s
print (df1)
  Data
0  dfs
1     
2     
3     
4     
5     
6     
7     
8
```

If empty strings are missing values:

```
data1 = [12,34,'fsdf',678,np.nan,np.nan,'dfs',np.nan,np.nan]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Data'])
print(df1)
   Data
0    12
1    34
2  fsdf
3   678
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   dfs
7   NaN
8   NaN

s = df1.loc[df1['Data'].iloc[::-1].notna().idxmax(), 'Data']
print (s)
dfs

df1['Data'] = ''
df1.loc[0, 'Data'] = s
print (df1)
  Data
0  dfs
1     
2     
3     
4     
5     
6     
7     
8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `''` with `NaN` using [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), now use [`df.last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html)

```
val = df1.loc[df1.replace('', np.nan).last_valid_index(), 'Data']

# Below two lines taken from @jezrael's answer
df1.loc[0, 'Data'] = val
df1.loc[1:, 'Data'] = ''
```

Or

You can use [`np.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) with `fill_value` set to `np.nan` here.

```
val = df1.loc[df1.replace("", np.nan).last_valid_index(), "Data"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.full(df1.shape, np.nan), 
                   index=df.index,
                   columns=df1.columns)

df1.loc[0, "Data"] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple pandas condition check like this can help,

```
df1['Data'] = [df1.loc[df1['Data'].ne(""), "Data"].iloc[-1]] + [''] * (len(df1) - 1)
```